# nginx server block property 'root' for rest api

Tags: nginx, nginx-config

Hi I've host a NodeJs RESTAPI on AWS EC2.
My nginx server block is like this

[image]

This gives me a warning in the nginx error logs.

> [warn] 5495#0: server name "/usr/share/nginx/html" has suspicious
>   symbols in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:42

This is a RESTapi so `root  /usr/share/nginx/html;` is ireleavant to this. But if I remove this line. `nginx` doesn't works.

How do I get rid of this error?

Any help!

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you don't have semicolon `;` after server_name value